# How to create a dataframe from a complex (nested) list of dictionaries?

Tags: python, dictionary

Good morning!

I have retrieved a bunch of data from the Facebook Graph API using the python facebook library. I'd like to organize all the meaningful data neatly in a csv file for later analysis, but the problem is I'm quite new to python and I don't know how to approach the format in which the data has been retrieved. Basically, I have all the data about a page posts from 01-05-2020 in a list called `data_basic`:

Every instance of the list represents one post and is a dict of size 8.

Every dict has: 3 dict elements, 3 string elements, 1 bool element and 1 list element.

For example, in order to access the media_type of the first post I must type: `data_basic[0]['attachments']['data'][0]['value']`, because inside the dict representing the first post I have a dict containing the attachments whose key 'data' contains a list in which I have the values (for example, again, media_type). A nightmare...

Every instance of the dict containing the post data is different... Attachment is the most nested, but something similar happens for the comments or the tags, while message, created time and so on are much more accessible.

I'd like to obtain a csv table whose rows are the various posts and whose columns are the variables (except, of course, the comments, which I'll store in a different file since there's more than one for each post).

How can I approach the problem? The first thing which comes to my mind is a brute force approach using a for cycle trough all the posts and all the variables, filling the dataframe place by place. But I hope there's a quicker and more elegant way... I've come across the `json_normalize` function, tried something, but I really don't understand how it works and if it can be of any help... Any thoughts?

Thanks in advance!

edit: a couple of screenshot in order to understand better

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please add an input sample, we well as the expected output, to the question.

Comment: Yeah, I'm sorry. I'll try the best I can to replicate here:

Comment: data_basic = {'0 : attachments'  = {{ 0 = 'media_type' : photo }, 'comments' = 0 : 'data' : created_time = 05-01-2020, 'value' = 'string of text' } , 'created_time' = '05-01-2020' , 'is_popular' = 'True' , {message_tags : LIST OF HASHTAGS with index : 'value'} , {shares : 'count' = 15} ,       {1 = 'media_ttype' : link etc...... }}

Comment: Please add the data (as well as the expected output) to the body of the question.

Comment: I've edited the question adding a couple of screenshot to better understand the context

Comment: to help one reproduce the issue, please include the input **as text** in the question. It's hard to copy & paste an image ...